# Specifying multiple alternatives in a single pattern match?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

Take the following function as an example (the function is quite meaningless but at least illustrates my question).

```
myFunction :: [x] -> x
myFunction [] = "result"
myFunction [x] = "result"
myFunction (_:xs) = myFunction xs
...
```

Since `myFunction []` and `myFunction x` matches produce the same result, is it possible to combine these into a single pattern-match rather than writing each one on a separate line and cut/pasting the result? Something like an "OR" operand:

```
myFunction [] || x = "result"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not as such, but there are a couple of alternatives to write it with one clause:

```
myFunction' (_:xs@(_:_)) = foo xs -- note the changed order: `_:...` first, thus
myFunction' _ = "result"          -- you'll get "result" for _every_ other input

myFunction'' xs | null $ drop 1 xs  = "result"  -- or `| [] <- drop 1 xs`
myFunction'' (_:xs) = foo xs

myFunction''' xs' = case drop 1 xs' of
       [] -> result
       xs -> foo xs
```

Comment: Accepted answer, because of the multiple alternative solutions.

Comment: I believe the first solution isn't correct, as `(_:xs)` also matches `[x]`. The third solution could be slightly simplified using [pattern guards](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pattern_guard).

Answer (score 2):

I should tell you that your `myFunction` doesn't actually typecheck. It should be like this:

```
myFunction :: [a] -> String
myFunction [] = "result"
myFunction [x] = "result"
myFunction (_:xs) = myFunction xs
```

That being said, what you want to do can be achieved through guards:

```
myFunction :: [a] -> String
myFunction xs
  | (null xs) || (length xs == 1) = "result"
  | otherwise = myFunction (tail xs)
```

Or a more efficient one in which you don't have to traverse the entire list:

```
 myFunction :: [a] -> String
    myFunction xs
      | (null xs) || null (tail xs) = "result"
      | otherwise = myFunction (tail xs)
```

Comment: @WillNess Updated with an efficient version :P

Answer (score 1):

How about this? Short and sweet:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-} 

myFunction ((<2) . length -> True) = "result"
myFunction _ = "other result"
```

You can replace `(<2) . length` by any other function of type `[a] -> Bool`, of course, *including lambdas* . As written, your example would probably be more precisely represented with first case

```
myFunction (\xs -> null xs || length xs == 1 -> True) = "result"
myFunction _ = "other result"
```

This is breaks for infinite lists, but that shouldn't be too hard to solve.

---

Finally, if you also enable the `LambdaCase` extension, you can even write

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns, LambdaCase #-} 

myFunction (\case { []->True ; [x]->True ; _->False } -> True) = "result"
myFunction _ = "other result"
```

That's getting unreadable and error prone (you have to make sure the `\case` expression is total! ) but it does combine two patterns into one, with only constant overhead. Don't do this, please :-)